# Minkowski sum alternative notation

Tags: notation

This is a LateX question on good notation.

The [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of two polytopes is pretty neat. I'm working with a lot of them right now, and Minkowski sum of simplices, which write as stuff like:

$$\sum y_I \, \mathrm{ conv } \{e_i | i \in I \}$$

So my problem arises when I want to talk about the vector space freely generated by these objects, so I have formal sums and Minkowski sums which should **absolutely not** have the same notation. When I'm adding two polytopes it's all good as I can use '+' and '+^M' and is reasonably clear. For the sum symbol I tried to use the '^M' trick but looks bad (looks like M is one of the limits of the sum).

Any ideas? Anyone that had a similar problem? Thanks!

Comment: `\sum\nolimits^M`?

Comment: It still looks like a limit if you have stuff in the lower line.